# How can I account for extra padding caused of the existence of a scrollbar with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I have an element which needs to be aligned with another element on a separate section of the page. However, this whole alignment is thrown off when the scrollbar appears.

What is the best way to handle the extra padding caused by the existence of this scrollbar if any so that the elements stay aligned regardless of the scrollbar existing?

Here is a sample app to illustrate what I mean:

```js
const App = () => {

  return (
  <div>
    <h4>Case 1: There is no scroll, so my items are aligned as expected:</h4>
    <div className="container">
      <div className='header'>
        <div className="element"/>
      </div>
      <div className='body'>
         <div>
          <div className="element"/>
        </div>
        <p>
          I can easily align the two blue squares by setting body and header to <strong>padding-right: 20px</strong>, because all my content fits without scroll
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
        <h4>Case 2: Now I have too much content, which needs to scroll, and my squares will be no longer aligned</h4>
        <div className="container">
      <div className='header'>
        <div className="element"/>
      </div>
      <div className='body'>
        <div>
          <div className="element"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align! Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align! Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align! Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align! Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align! Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align! Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align! Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align! Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align! Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align! Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align! Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 20px;
}

.body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.element {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: You could use the non standard CSS selector `::-webkit-scrollbar` with a defined width that you can control, but that won't work on firefox.

Comment: You can use the experimental [`scrollbar-gutter: stable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-gutter#stable) property-value pair: otherwise [`overflow-y: overlay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#overlay) (deprecated but not yet fully so) will potentially solve your issue.

Comment: @Terry although overflow-y:overlay definitely does the job, but unfortunately it isn't on the table due to being deprecated and not working on all browsers :(

Answer (score 1):

If the width of `.container` is always known, you can use it to define the width of an inner element inside the `.body` one:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 20px;
}

.body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.body > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}

.element {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

* {
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<h4>Case 2: Now I have too much content, which needs to scroll, and my squares will be no longer aligned</h4>
<div class="container">
  <div class='header'>
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class='body'>
   <div>
    <div>
      <div class="element"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align! Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align! Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align! Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align! Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align! Scrollbar made
      my blue squares no longer align! Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align! Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align! Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align! Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align! Scrollbar made my blue
      squares no longer align! Scrollbar made my blue squares no longer align!
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this cross-browser? I mean is the width of the (overflown) scrollbar always 20px?

Comment: @DarkBee 20px is the padding the OP want, not the scrollbar width. We don't need to know the scrollbar width

Comment: I see, currently having a similar issue with a flex-table I made but something is off on responsive view (with the borders). But your solutions works in a responsive view, so I overlooked something.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try Hiding the scroll bars

```
body {
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide scrollbars */
}
```

and try to minify the overall body width

Comment: Wish it were that easy. I need the scrollbars.